# How do i get the name or identification of a marker JVectorMap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

How do I know the `name` or `id` of the marker that is clicked?

And is it possible?

Is there a way to find the `label/name` of the marker like this for example:

```js
onMarkerClick: function(label){
    alert(label.text());
}
```

All help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter in the click handler function is the key/index of the marker object.

> *onMarkerClick (Event e, String code)*

One possible way to do that, is:

```
onMarkerClick: function(e, code) {
    var mapObj = $("#map").vectorMap("get", "mapObject");
    var idx = parseInt(code); // optional
    var name = mapObj.markers[idx].config.name;
    var latitude = mapObj.markers[idx].config.latLng[0];
    var longitude = mapObj.markers[idx].config.latLng[1];
}
```

Explanation:

- depending how you created the markers, you may need to get the index
  as numeric value
- by default, each marker is storing the `name` and the `coords` of the point

If you need more info, try to explore the properties of the map object in the browser, like this: `console.log(mapObj.markers);`

Comment: Hmm seems like a good solution but i only end up with an error telling me that getMapObject cannot be read. It points to an error with the jvectormap js script. Probably something i have done wrong :/

Comment: check the element where you have put your map: `$("#map")` should contain that `id`. If doesn't work, post some markup ;)

Comment: Oh yeah my map is called world-map not map. Going to Try it now